# Make link to public file in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a file /public/animals/mammals/pets/d/dog.jpg in the Rails project. So it can be accessed via the URL `/animals/mammals/pets/d/dog.jpg`. Is there a way to make it accessible from a shorter URL, e.g. `/dog-picture` links to `/animals/mammals/pets/d/dog.jpg`?

Comment: a little trick is creating a dir under public folder and make it a symbol link to the deep one.

Comment: Do you mean using the Linux command `ln -s` to create a symbolic link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to explicitly use the :controller and :action symbols within a route. You can supply them as defaults:

```
match 'photos/:id' => 'photos#show'
```

With this route, Rails will match an incoming path of /photos/12 to the `show` action of `PhotosController`.

You can also define other defaults in a route by supplying a hash for the :defaults option. This even applies to parameters that you do not specify as dynamic segments. For example:

```
match 'photos/:id' => 'photos#show', :defaults => { :format => 'jpg' }
```

Rails would match photos/12 to the show action of `PhotosController`, and set `params[:format]` to `jpg`.

And also refer to: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution is to make a controller to handle the image request. You could then move images out of the public folder.

Though to be honest I'm not sure having a long url is really a problem apart from maybe ascetics.